# Looping through Json and appending to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON response from Google Maps, saved to a .json file. It's a search for schools nearby.

I only want to extract the name and the location of the schools, and save these to the `elemSchoolsArr` variable for use later.

I don't know why the code I have below doesn't loop through the json response, checking `elemSchoolsObj` only show one object, instead of 10, which I would want to push to the `elemSchoolsArr` later.

```
var elemSchoolsArr = [];
var elemSchoolsObj = {};

$.getJSON('elementary-schools.json', function(data){
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    elemSchoolsObj.title = data.results[i].name;
    elemSchoolsObj.location = data.results[i].geometry.location;

  }
});

elemSchoolsArr.push(elemSchoolsObj);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to push the object in to the array inside of the loop, so that each object is pushed in, rather than just one. Obviously this code snippet won't actually run because we're not getting your JSON here.

```js
var elemSchoolsArr = [];

$.getJSON('elementary-schools.json', function(data){
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var elemSchoolsObj = {};
    elemSchoolsObj.title = data.results[i].name;
    elemSchoolsObj.location = data.results[i].geometry.location;
    elemSchoolsArr.push(elemSchoolsObj);
  }
});
```

Here's a functional example...

```js
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var first_try = [];
var second_try = [];

for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){
  // we define our object in the loop but don't add it to the array
  var obj = {
   item: array[i]
  };
}

// we push one object in to the array
first_try.push( obj );

// we get one object in the array
console.log( first_try );

for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){
  // we define our object in the loop
  var obj = {
   item: array[i]
  };
  // we push each object we define in the loop in to the array
 second_try.push( obj );
}

// we get all the objects in the array
console.log( second_try );
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)